# Relative links in an included html not working due to directory structure. Is there a way around?

Tags: html, hyperlink, relative-path

I have a project directory structure like this:

```
proj
|__index.html
|__about_us.html
|__header.html
|__inner_folder
   |__another_page.html
```

Now the header has a link to about_us.html file and the header is included in all the files (using jquery).

If I give a relative link in header.html as:

```
<a href="./about_us.html>About us</a>
```

it will work in the index.html page as it is at the same level as the about_us.html page. But this link in the header will not work in the another_page.html as it is not at the same level.

Now, the url on local machine for index.html is like: localhost:63342/proj/index.html

If I give the link in the header as:

```
<a href="/about_us.html">About us</a>
```

then the link that gets formed is localhost:63342/about_us.html (without the /proj/..) which returns a 404.

Is there a way to get the links to work on all the pages using relative paths?

I cannot use absolute paths or the project name in the path as those do not work on the remote environments where the domain is different.

Is there a way to get around this?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to go from another_page.html and link to a page that is one directory up, use ../  like this:

```
<a href="../index.html">go to index.html from another_page.html</a>
```

If you are linking to a page in the same directory (from index.html), you use ./ like this:

```
<a href="./about_us.html">go to about_us.html from index.html</a>
```

Comment: Yes I understand that. But there is just one file (header.html) which I need to include in other html pages which might be present in different directories. How do I give the link in that header.html file for it to work on all the pages correctly and also on remote environments?

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood what you were hoping to accomplish.  You need to link from the root directory which is just a forward slash (/), then relative from there.  So, if you were linking from your header file to index.html, it would be <a href="/proj/index.html"></a>.  If you linking to another sub-directory it would be <a href="/proj/inner_folder/another_page.html"></a>.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: If i give the link as /proj/about_us.html, this link works fine on my local machine but it fails on the environments as the the links there are mydomain.com/index.html and not mydomain.com/proj/index.html.

If I give the link as /about_us.html, it works fine on the remote as the url becomes mydomain.com/index.html but it fails locally as localhost:port/index.html will give 404 but localhost:port/proj/index.html will work.

So, I basically need something which will work both on local machine as well as the environment. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: your links have to be specific to the environment that they are going to be deployed in, unless you're using some server-side code that can determine the root of the project and navigate from there.  for instance, in asp.net, you would use the tilde character to navigate to the root of the project/application (~/index.html)